# Javascript Jest Unit Test Date Timespan for Today and Day before

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I want to Test my Timespan for Today and Day before with Jest but i dont know how i should do it.
Maybe someone can tell me how it works? I am new with writing Unit Test..

Here is my Code i want to Test:

```
export const getToday = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  return today;
}

export const getDayBefore = (date) => {
  const day = new Date(date);
  day.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  return day;
}
```

This is what ive done now, but its not working.

```
describe('getToday', () => {
    it('should checks "today"', () => {
        const ts1 = Date.now();
        expect(ts1).toEqual(getToday);
    })
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `expect(ts1).toEqual(getToday);` be `expect(ts1).toEqual(getToday());`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the corrected code, I'd advise swapping the assertion and the function around so the test makes more sense. You should be running a function and expecting it to equal a value instead of the other way round.

`Date.now()` does not equal `new Date()` as the former returns a numeric representation of the date and the latter returns a Date object, therefore they do not match.

```
export const getToday = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  return today;
}

describe('getToday', () => {
  it('matches todays date', () => {
      const now = new Date();
      expect(getToday()).toEqual(now);
  });
});
```

### Updated, get date before

I've reworked the function to make the date arg optional so that it returns yesterday date by default. We can't just pass null into the Date constructor or else this will return 01-01-1970. See below example.

```
const getDayBefore = (date = null) => {
  const day = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
  day.setDate(day.getDate() - 1);
  return day;
};

describe("getDayBefore", () => {
  it("returns yesterdays date", () => {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    expect(getDayBefore()).toEqual(date);
  });

  it("returns the correct date if 31/12/2021 was supplied as the date arg", () => {
    const date = new Date(2021, 11, 30); // month has an offset of 11 (11 = december)
    expect(getDayBefore('2021-12-31')).toEqual(date);
  });

  it("returns the correct date if 24/02/1900 was supplied as the date arg", () => {
    const date = new Date(1990, 1, 23); // month has an offset of 1 (1 = feb)
    expect(getDayBefore('1990-02-24')).toEqual(date);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) But how do i test the getDayBefore? Should i just add -1 in the param?

Comment: @tripleD if it helped, please mark as answer :)